# How to add an id to an inflated view?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am dynamically adding views to my layout by using layout inflater, but I am trying to add an id to every new view that gets added so I can use a getter to extract the information.

I am also trying to change the array data in the new spinner that gets added in each view as it is currently showing the default string array and not the array that I read from my database

```
public void onAddField(View v) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field, null);
        // Add the new row before the add field button.
        getdata2();
        parentLinearLayout.addView(rowView, parentLinearLayout.getChildCount() - 1);
        Log.d(String.valueOf(rowView.getId()), "onAddField: ");
        getdata2();

    }

private void getdata2() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest("http://.../getDataCategories.php",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        JSONObject j = null;
                        try {
                            j = new JSONObject(response);
                            result = j.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);
                            catdetails(result);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    }
                });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void catdetails(JSONArray j) {
        for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);
                arrayList2.add(json.getString(CategoryType_idArray));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        type2_workout_mySpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, arrayList2));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add id as tag inside view object 
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field, null);
rowView.setTag(1);

consider number as your view id and get this id as getTag().

You can also update the array data and spinner update using above.
Like get a child from parentLinearLayout using parentLinearLayout.getchildAt() and then get the spinner from view and the again set adapter into the spinner.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I am not sure if I understand this correctly but this is what I have tried according to what I understand from your answer.. Is this correct?


int a = 1;
...
        final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field, null);
        rowView.setTag(a);
        parentLinearLayout.addView(rowView, parentLinearLayout.getChildCount() - 1);
        Log.d(String.valueOf(rowView.getTag(a)), "onAddField: " + 
        parentLinearLayout.getChildAt(a).getTag());
        a = a +1;
    }

Comment: I am struggling to set the adapter into the spinner again. How would I use a getter method to for example see the selected item that I picked from the new view's spinner? Will this be able to show multiple values for example if I have selected something on the spinner from  multiple views and then will this values be stored as a new array so that I can save it to a database?